# SessionAuthenticationModule TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie does not work after RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 application (with WebApi).

SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie seems to work. (It shows a cookie with "FedAuth".

But after a RedirectToAction, the corresponding TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie does not work, and there are no "FedAuth" cookies.

A different cookie that I set does show up correctly.  (Proving that cookies are enabled on the browser)

"foundCp" is null.  And the "FedAuth" cookies aren't there in the Request (after the RediretToAction)

(Setup)
If you start a new Web Project, and create a new MVC4 application (with sub-kind as "WebApi", you can paste the below code in (overwriting HomeController.cs) to get the code to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SessionAuthenticationModuleQuickDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private const string MyCustomCookieName = "MyCustomCookieName";
        private const string IISExpressRootUrl = "http://localhost:25815/"; /* open up the project properties and go to the web tab and find the iis-express area to get the correct value for your environment */

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            IEnumerable<string> webApiValues = null;
            string value1 = null;
            string value2 = null;

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                PreAuthenticate = true
            };


            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {

                string valuesUri = IISExpressRootUrl + "api/Values";

                webApiValues = client
                            .GetAsync(valuesUri)
                            .Result
                            .Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>().Result;

                if (null != webApiValues)
                {
                    value1 = webApiValues.ElementAt(0);
                    value2 = webApiValues.ElementAt(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("WebApi call failed");
                }
            }


            HttpCookie customCookie = new HttpCookie(MyCustomCookieName, "CustomCookieValue_ThisShowsUpIn_MyHomeControllerAlternateActionResult_Method");
            Response.Cookies.Add(customCookie);




            ClaimsIdentity cid = new ClaimsIdentity("HomeController.ActionResult.Index");
            for (int i = 100; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                cid.AddClaim(new Claim("ForLoop_Claim", Convert.ToString(i)));
            }
            ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(cid);
            SessionSecurityToken token = new SessionSecurityToken(cp);
            token.IsPersistent = false;
            token.IsReferenceMode = true;
            SessionAuthenticationModule sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
            sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);

            int fedAuthCookieCountBeforeRedirect = 0;
            foreach (string cookiename in Response.Cookies)
            {
                var cookie = Request.Cookies[cookiename];

                if (cookie.Name.StartsWith("FedAuth", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    fedAuthCookieCountBeforeRedirect++;
                }
            }

            if (fedAuthCookieCountBeforeRedirect <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No FedAuth cookies found");
            }


            return RedirectToAction("MyHomeControllerAlternateActionResult");
        }

        public ActionResult MyHomeControllerAlternateActionResult()
        {

            ClaimsPrincipal foundCp = null;
            SessionSecurityToken outResultSessionSecurityToken = null;

            SessionAuthenticationModule sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;

            SessionSecurityToken contextSst = sam.ContextSessionSecurityToken;
            if (null == foundCp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ContextSessionSecurityToken did not work :<");
            }

            bool result = sam.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(out outResultSessionSecurityToken);
            if (result)
            {
                foundCp = outResultSessionSecurityToken.ClaimsPrincipal;
            }

            if (null == foundCp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie did not work :<");
            }


            IEnumerable<string> webApiReturnValues = null;

            int fedAuthCookieCountAfterRedirect = 0;
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            foreach (string cookiename in Request.Cookies)
            {
                var cookie = Request.Cookies[cookiename];

                if (cookie.Name.Equals(MyCustomCookieName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, "localhost"));
                }
                if (cookie.Name.StartsWith("FedAuth", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    fedAuthCookieCountAfterRedirect++;
                }
            }

            if (fedAuthCookieCountAfterRedirect <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No FedAuth After Redirect cookies found  :<   ");
            }

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseCookies = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                CookieContainer = cookieContainer
            };


            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {


                string valuesUri = IISExpressRootUrl + "api/Values";

                webApiReturnValues = client
                            .GetAsync(valuesUri)
                            .Result
                            .Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>().Result;

                if (null == webApiReturnValues)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("WebApi call failed");
                }

            }

            return View(); /* this will throw a "The view 'MyHomeControllerAlternateActionResult' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations" error, but that's not the point of this demo. */
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Services;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SessionAuthenticationModuleQuickDemo
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {

            //SUBSCRIBE TO SAM EVENTS
            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SessionSecurityTokenCreated += new EventHandler<SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs>(SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated);


            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        public override void Init()
        {
            var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
            sam.IsReferenceMode = true;
        }

        void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Handling SessionSecurityTokenCreated event");
            //Store session on the server-side token cache instead writing the whole token to the cookie.
            //It may improve throughput but introduces server affinity that may affect scalability
            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.IsReferenceMode = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Relevant web.config parts:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
      <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>


<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <!--WIF 4.5 modules -->
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

  <!-- Adding the below causes a "ID0006: The input string parameter is either null or empty. Parameter name: Issuer" error -->
  <!--<add name="WsFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>-->
</modules>

  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <clear />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        </add>
      </securityTokenHandlers>

    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

Full web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
      <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SessionAuthenticationModuleQuickDemo-20151014083716;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SessionAuthenticationModuleQuickDemo-20151014083716.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <!--WIF 4.5 modules -->
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

      <!-- Adding the below causes a "ID0006: The input string parameter is either null or empty. Parameter name: Issuer" error -->
      <!--<add name="WsFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>-->
    </modules>


  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>



  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <clear />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        </add>
      </securityTokenHandlers>

    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>



</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:

http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/28/claims-based-authentication-in-mvc4-with-net4-5-c-part-2-storing-authentication-data-in-an-authentication-session/

*By default the authentication session feature will only work through SSL. This is well and good but may be an overkill for a local demo app. To disable it let’s add the following bit of XML somewhere within the configuration element in web.config:*

By putting the below in (at the bottom of web.config)........it now works.

```
      <system.identityModel.services>
        <federationConfiguration>
          <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        </federationConfiguration>
      </system.identityModel.services>

</configuration>
```

Full web.config for kicks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SessionAuthenticationModuleQuickDemo-20151014083716;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SessionAuthenticationModuleQuickDemo-20151014083716.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <!--WIF 4.5 modules -->
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

      <!-- Adding the below causes a "ID0006: The input string parameter is either null or empty. Parameter name: Issuer" error -->
      <!--<add name="WsFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>-->
    </modules>


  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>



  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <clear /> <!-- Note the CLEAR here -->
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        </add>
      </securityTokenHandlers>

    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>


  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>



</configuration>
```